# Google Search Console coverage reports "Submitted URL marked 'noindex'" for a 404 page not in the sitemap without a noindex tag

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt, noindex, coverage

**Error:** "Submitted URL marked 'noindex'" error in the Google Search Console coverage report

**Situation**

- URL is not submitted in our sitemap
- Google is not indexing the URL
- There is no `noindex` tag on the page
- The URL is not disallowed in `robots.txt`
- Can't find the file on server and it returns a 404 on front-end
- Resubmitted the sitemap and the error persists

Has anyone encountered this situation? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed without doing anything further. If you are in a similar situation, just be patient. Apparently it takes a month or two for Google to validate.